# Class capacity function does not work properly

Tags: c++, function, insert

I am writing a capacity function inside the push back function to return the size of the storage space currently allocated for the vector array. It is during the insert test case as shown below that it did not work properly (Look at the capacity). The insert works smoothly but the capacity does not work properly and somehow resulted in aborted core dumped at the end of it. Could someone highlight to me why that is? Thanks!

Incorrect output:

```
********** TestInsert **********
(size=0, capacity=0)
push_back 8 floats:
    0  (size=1, capacity=1)
    0   1.41  (size=2, capacity=2)
    0   1.41   2.82  (size=3, capacity=4)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24  (size=4, capacity=4)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65  (size=5, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06  (size=6, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47  (size=7, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  (size=8, capacity=8)
insert(3, 99):
    0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  (size=9, 
capacity=8)
insert(0, 98):
    98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  
(size=10, capacity=8)
insert(6, 97):
    98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24     97   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  (size=11, capacity=8)
Construct from int array:
6  6  16  14  -6  12  6  10  8  6  6  4  2  0  (size=14, capacity=1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Correct output:

```
********** TestInsert **********
(size=0, capacity=0)
push_back 8 floats:
    0  (size=1, capacity=1)
    0   1.41  (size=2, capacity=2)
    0   1.41   2.82  (size=3, capacity=4)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24  (size=4, capacity=4)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65  (size=5, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06  (size=6, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47  (size=7, capacity=8)
    0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  (size=8, capacity=8)
insert(3, 99):
    0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  (size=9, 
capacity=16)
insert(0, 98):
    98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  
(size=10, capacity=16)
insert(6, 97):
    98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24     97   5.65   7.06   8.47   9.89  
(size=11, capacity=16)
Construct from int array:
6  6  16  14  -6  12  6  10  8  6  6  4  2  0  (size=14, capacity=16)
```

Header file:

```
template <typename T>
class vec
{

private:
T* v;
int count; //size
int capacity;
public:

vector(){ //default constructor
    capacity=0;
    v = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}

vector(const vector& b) //copy contructor
{
//..
}   

~vector() {//destructor
//..
}

void push_back(const T& t) // contain the capacity 
{
    if(count+1>capacity)
{
    capacity = std::max(2*capacity, 1);

    T* newData = new T[capacity];
    for(int i=0; i <count; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = v[i];
    }
    delete[] v;
    v = newData;
}
v[count++] = t;
}

void insert(int index, T number)
{
    for (int i = count; i >= index; i--) {
        v[i + 1] = v[i];
    }

    count++;
    v[index] = number;
}

template <typename T1>
friend void Print(const vector<T1>& rp); //friend print

friend  void Print(const vector<float>& rp);    
};

template <typename T1>
void Print (const vector<T1>& rp)
{
for (unsigned i = 0; i < rp.size(); i++)
std::cout << rp[i] << "  ";
std::cout << "(size=" << rp.size()<< "," << " " << "capacity=" 
<< rp.capacity << ")"; 
std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Print (const vector<float>& rp)
{   
for (unsigned i = 0; i < rp.size(); i++)
{     
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(3)
    << float (rp[i]) <<"  ";
}    
std::cout << "(size=" << rp.size()<< "," << " " << "capacity=" 
<< rp.capacity << ")"; 
std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

main file:

```
void TestInsert(void)
{
{
cout << "\n********** TestInsert **********\n";
cs150::vector<float> a;
Print(a);

cout << "push_back 8 floats:\n";
for( float i = 0; i < 8; ++i ) 
{
  a.push_back( i * 1.412492f );
  Print(a);
}

cout << "insert(3, 99):\n";
a.insert(3, 99);
Print(a);

cout << "insert(0, 98):\n";
a.insert(0, 98);
Print(a);

cout << "insert(6, 97):\n";
a.insert(6, 97);
Print(a);
}
{
int ia[] = { 
  2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 6, 12, -6, 14, 16, 6, 6 
};

std::size_t size = sizeof( ia ) / sizeof( *ia );

std::cout << "Construct from int array:\n";
cs150::vector<int> a;

a.push_back( 0 );

for( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
  a.insert( 0, ia[i] );

Print(a);
}
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
std::size_t test_num = 0;

if( argc > 1 )
    test_num = std::size_t( std::atoi( argv[ 1 ] ) );

typedef void (*Test)( void );

Test Tests[] = {

TestInsert,             //  4

};

std::size_t num = sizeof( Tests ) / sizeof( *Tests );

if( test_num == 0 ) 
{
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i )
  Tests[ i ]();
} 
else if( test_num <= num )
{
    Tests[ test_num - 1 ]();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189357/discussion-on-question-by-playpro0-class-capacity-function-does-not-work-properl).

Comment: You… don’t reallocate in `insert`?